# How to capture time spent inactive in Qualtrics

Tags: time, focus, blur, onblur, onfocus

Hi I am trying to measure if people are cheating by leaving the Qualtrics survey. I want to know how long they spend outside of the quiz window. I found a few answers on this website, but my javascript does not send the data to embeddeddata. Here is my script that I put in the Header of my Quiz(please keep in mind that I started to learn Java yesterday):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {

var log = "${e://Field/total}";
(function() {


var time = 0,
    delta = 100,
    tid;

tid = setInterval(function() {
    if ( window.blurred ) { return; }    
   total = ((time+=delta)/1000); 
   log.text(total);
}, delta);
})();

window.onblur = function() { window.blurred = false; alert("YOLO!")};
window.onfocus = function() { window.blurred = true; };

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('total', log);
});
</script>
```